# Adding sample size data to pie chart in R (mapplots package)

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have been able to plot several pie charts overtop a map, representing different populations. However, what I would like to do is somehow represent the sample size for each of the pie charts, as its differs between population. I have a loop to add each population present in the dataset as a pie chart:

```
map("worldHires", xlim=c(-140, -110), ylim=c(48, 64), col="lightgray", fill=TRUE)
points(x=-120.43,y=50.34, col="black", pch=19)
segments(x0=dataframe$Long, y0=dataframe$Lat, x1=dataframe$Long2, y1=dataframe$Lat2, col="black")
add.pie(z=c(2, 5, 6),x=-122.43,y=52.34,labels="",radius = 1)
for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe))
{
  add.pie(as.integer(dataframe[i,c("Cat1","Cat2", "Cat3")]*100),
          x=dataframe$Long2[i],y=dataframe$Lat2[i],labels="",radius = 0.08,
          col=c("red","blue", "green"))
}
title(ylab="Latitude")
title(xlab="Longitude")
box(which="plot")
```

I would like to add the sample size data (dataframe$n) somehow. I've seen examples of scaled radius pie charts, which could work here, or even just adding the sample size above the pie chart. To get the sample size above the pie chart I tried adding 'main=dataframe$n' between labels and radius in the add.pie portion of the code, but this did not work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to add this to my script? Thank you.

Comment: It is necessary that provide us an example to replicate

Answer (score 0):

The size of each pie is plotted according each value in your dataframe. The good dataframe for this has a stations as rows and the class type are columns